# Show that the solutions is a subspace of $\mathbb R^5$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Show that the solutions for the linear system of equations:
>
> $$\begin{aligned} 0 + x_2 +3x_3 - x_4 + 2x_5 &= 0 \\ 2x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 + 3x_4 &= 0 \\ x_1 + x_2 - x_3 + 2x_4 - x_5 &= 0 \end{aligned}$$
>
> is a subspace of $\mathbb R^5$. What is the dimension of the subspace and determine a basis for the subspace?

I really don't know how to solve this problem. I have achieved this augmented matrix through Gaussian elimination:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1&  0&  -4&  3&  -3&  0 \\ 
 0&  1&  3&  -1&  2&  0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Any hints or some steps I've missed?

**Edit**

My professor says the dimension is $3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Now your free variables are $x_3=s$,$x_4=t$ and $x_5=u$. Using backward substitution we get
$$
x_1=4s-3t+3u \\
x_2=-3s+t-2u\\
x_3=s \\
x_4=t \\
x_5=u
$$

Therefore we can write every solution as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5
\end{bmatrix}=s\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
-3 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}+u\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
-2 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $s,t,u \in \mathbb{R}$.

Thus the subspace has dimension $3$ and a basis is given by $\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
-3 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
-2 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

To prove is a subspace you need:

- $0$ belongs to it: this is clear by taking $s=t=u=0$
- It's closed under sums: if $(s,t,u)$ and $(s',t',u')$ gives us two different solutions, the sum of them is given by $(s+s',t+t',u+u')$
- It's closed under scalar multiplication: if $(s,t,u)$ gives us a solution and we multiply it by $k \in \mathbb{R}$, then we still have a solution given by $(ks,kt,ku)$.

Therefore it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$

Comment: missing $s$ in equation 2

Comment: Thank for you your answer, this was also thought on this problem. However, my professor says that the Dim = 3, which I can't really see why, or maybe he has made a mistake?

Also, how do I argument that the solutions is a subspace of R5?

Comment: @Carl are you sure about your Gaussian elimination then? Because in that case the dimension is $2$. To get dimension $3$ you need that one of the rows becomes of all zeros

Comment: I'm very, very sorry. I messed up on my augmented matrix. I have updated my question and the augmented matrix, although I think I understand the solution now, it would be very generous of you to edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correct  RREF: 
\begin{align}
&\left[\begin{array}{*{5}{r}}
0&1&3&-1&2 \\
2&3&1&3&0 \\
1&1&-1&2&-1
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{*{5}{r}}
1&1&-1&2&-1 \\
0&1&3&-1&2 \\
2&3&1&3&0
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{*{5}{r}}
1&1&-1&2&-1 \\
0&1&3&-1&2 \\
0&1&3&-1&2
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow \\[1ex]
&\left[\begin{array}{*{5}{r}}
1&1&-1&2&-1 \\
0&1&3&-1&2 \\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{*{5}{r}}
1&0&-4&3&-3 \\
0&1&3&-1&2 \\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right].
\end{align}
This matrix has rank $2$.  Hence, by the *rank-nullity theorem*, the kernel, i. e. the subspace of solutions (in a $5$-dimensional space), has dimension $3$.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a good answer on what that subspace is and what dimension it has.

To prove that we are indeed talking about a subspace, you  must prove that:

- If $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)$ and $(y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5)$ are solutions, then $(x_1 + y_1, x_2 + y_2, x_3 + y_3, x_4 + y_4, x_5 + y_5)$ is also a solution
- If $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)$ is a solution and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then $(\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2, \lambda x_3, \lambda x_4, \lambda x_5)$ is also a solution